# How to set all values in a column = 0 where the values in a selection of columns are duplicated, while keeping the first duplicated value intact

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a `df` that looks similar to this, except the number of material columns goes up to `material_19` and there are over 1000 clients.

```
Client_ID  Visit_DT   material_1  material_2  material_3  material_4
C001       2019-01-01 1           0           1           0
C002       2019-01-05 0           1           0           0
C003       2019-01-10 1           0           1           0
C001       2019-01-15 1           0           0           1
C002       2019-01-20 1           1           1           0
```

Where a material is used more than once by the same client across different dates (indicated by a `1` appearing in the same `material` column across multiple rows for the same `Client_ID`), I would like to set all of the values in that `material` column equal to `0` in those rows where this duplication has occurred, with the exception of the value in the first duplicated row. The resulting df should look like this:

```
Client_ID  Visit_DT   material_1  material_2  material_3  material_4
C001       2019-01-01 1           0           1           0
C002       2019-01-05 0           1           0           0
C003       2019-01-10 1           0           1           0
C001       2019-01-15 0           0           0           1
C002       2019-01-20 1           0           1           0
```

Comment: So is the requirement, grouped by Client_ID, for each column set all values after the first non-zero value to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
material_cols = ['material_1', 'material_2', 'material_3', 'material_4']
mask = df.groupby('Client_ID').cumsum() == 1
df[material_cols] = df[material_cols]*mask
```

Which results in

```
df
Out[27]: 
  Client_ID    Visit_DT  material_1  material_2  material_3  material_4
0      C001  2019-01-01           1           0           1           0
1      C002  2019-01-05           0           1           0           0
2      C003  2019-01-10           1           0           1           0
3      C001  2019-01-15           1           0           0           1
4      C002  2019-01-20           1           1           1           0
material_cols = ['material_1', 'material_2', 'material_3', 'material_4']
mask = df.groupby('Client_ID').cumsum() == 1
df[material_cols] = df[material_cols] * mask
df
Out[29]: 
  Client_ID    Visit_DT  material_1  material_2  material_3  material_4
0      C001  2019-01-01           1           0           1           0
1      C002  2019-01-05           0           1           0           0
2      C003  2019-01-10           1           0           1           0
3      C001  2019-01-15           0           0           0           1
4      C002  2019-01-20           1           0           1           0
```

Note depending on your DataFrame you might be able to replace `df[material_cols]` with `df.iloc[:, 2:]`

Comment: Thanks for responding. My df actually has a few more columns other than the material, date, and client ID columns that I did not mention at the beginning of the question - I didn't think they were relevant and I didn't want to confuse things. When I remove those extra columns I get the correct output and your code works perfectly. However, with the extra columns in (and it would preferable if I could keep them in) everything runs except the last line, at which point I get the following error message: 'Columns must be same length as key'. Any ideas?

Comment: The issue was that one of the extra columns was a float dtype, which meant `cumsum()` was counting the values in that column as well as the material columns, hence `mask` had one more column than `material_cols`. I converted that column to string, and the code now works perfectly.

Comment: @FGreen instead of converting it to a string, it probably makes more sense to slice your df to exclude it to when you generate the mask. Your code will more closely match your intentions that way and be easier to follow.

Comment: Thanks @Dan - how do I do that?

Comment: using `.loc` or `.iloc`. It depends on which fileds you want. If your 'material' fields are always at the end, then if they start from column n do `.iloc[:, n:]`. If they're in the middle, then you'll need to find them somehow. One way would be to use df.columns to get a list of the strings of the column names and then drop all the names that don't start with 'material_'. But this is really a separate question. I suggest you attempt it yourself and if you get stuck, ask a new question.

Comment: I used something similar to the df.columns method and it worked, thanks again for the advice. Although I'm curious how this works - is it a general rule that when you groupby with cumsum, the df remains 'long' i.e. it doesn't actually reduce the df down to unique instances of the index, as would be the case with sum, for example? Also, just to check my understanding, is it that when you multiply the columns by the mask, where the mask instances = False, it turns the values in the columns to 0?

Comment: @FGreen I'm making those same assumptions. Regarding `cumsum` after a groupby [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) are not informative. It appears to do what you're describing. Regarding multiplying by a bool, it appears to me that multiplying by `True` leaves the value and type unchanged, multiplying by `False` leaves the type the same but makes it falsey (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)